# How to use Microsoft Graph API chatMessage to send a message with clickable hyperlink in it

Tags: microsoft-teams

According the official [guidebook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) I'm able to send Microsoft Teams message using Microsoft graph API, the message contains a link, and the receiver received the message as plain text, the link is not clickable,    how to send a message that enable the receiver to click on it if it's text content with links in it?

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/fbe2bf47-16c8-47cf-b4a5-4b9b187c508b/channels/19:4a95f7d8db4c4e7fae857bcebe0623e6@thread.tacv2/messages
Content-type: application/json

{
  "body": {
    "content": "Hello Dan, please go to www.microsoft.com"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Teams message support a subset of markdown syntax, so you can encode your link appropriately. More info here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-markdown-formatting-in-teams-4d10bd65-55e2-4b2d-a1f3-2bebdcd2c772

In principle, your example would look like this:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/fbe2bf47-16c8-47cf-b4a5-4b9b187c508b/channels/19:4a95f7d8db4c4e7fae857bcebe0623e6@thread.tacv2/messages
```

Content-type: application/json

{
"body": {
"content": "Hello Dan, please go to [www.microsoft.com] (https://www.microsoft.com)"
}
}

(I've put a space between ']' and '(' just so it renders here in Stack Overflow properly - remove it before testing. I needed to do that because Stack Overflow *itself* support is trying to render my markdown)